# With the SVG package, is it possible to set the output folder to be the same as the input folder?

Tags: graphics, svg, inkscape

I am trying to use the [`svg`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/svg) package for LaTeX, which in my case also relies on Inkscape 1.0, to easily include SVG files in my compiled PDF. However, it wants to create all of its outputs in one folder in the working directory called 'svg-inkscape' by default. Is there a way to tell the package to feed Inkscape an output path that matches the input file path?

A sample of my directory looks like this:

```
├── main.tex
├── Makefile
├── chapter-1
│   ├── figures
│   │   └── figure-1.svg
│   └── chapter-1.tex
└── svg-inkscape
    └── figure-1.pdf         <-- is in another folder than the SVG
```

My ideal outcome would be to have

```
├── main.tex
├── Makefile
└── chapter-1
    ├── figures
    │   ├── figure-1.svg
    │   └── figure-1.pdf     <-- sits next to SVG
    └── chapter-1.tex
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is, that's what the option `inkscapepath` is for:

```latex
\usepackage[inkscapearea=page, inkscapepath=svgdir]{svg}
```

---

In my experience, though, it is a blessing not to have these temporary files clutter the image folder. It avoids confusing messes and enables you to easily delete them all (say you want to re-export all drawings or you want to copy only the necessary files somewhere). If what bugs you is that images from all chapters are in one folder, I would recommend you use `svgsubdir` instead. This will create a folder named `svg-inkscape/` for temporary files in the folder where the `svg` resides.

```latex
\usepackage[inkscapearea=page, inkscapepath=svgsubdir]{svg}
```

Comment: Thank you! I had gotten confused by the output setting parameters in the SVG section (B.1.3) of the documentation. Clearly, I should have looked more into the general settings!